# PHP Syntax Highlight in Sublime Text

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext

I've got issues with syntax highlighting in following cases:

[image]

How can I get variables highlighted when mixed with strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to have a color scheme that has the correct scopes. For example, this is how similar code looks like using the [Neon Color Scheme](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme):

[image: PHP $var in string]

Answer (score 1):

I use this kind of highlight: [image]

It helps me a lot when php code is together with other html code.

You have to edit your theme .tmTheme file, as mine is Monokay.tmTheme so right after the `</array>` command i used the code above:

```
    <dict>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>punctuation.section.embedded.begin.php</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#FF0000</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>

    <dict>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>punctuation.section.embedded.end.php</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#FF0000</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```